Setting coefficients to zero in optimization problem
My textbook (optimal control by Kirk) states that, when a function $f(y_1,y_2)$ is subject to a constraint, you cannot simply set $\partial{f}/\partial{y_1}$ and $\partial{f}/\partial{y_2}$ equal to zero to find the extremum because $\Delta{y_1}$ and $\Delta{y_2}$ are not independent. I get that $\Delta{y_1}$ and $\Delta{y_2}$ depend on each other due to the constraint but why does that prevent us from being able to set $\partial{f}/\partial{y_1}$ and $\partial{f}/\partial{y_2}$ equal to zero to find the extremum? Why is that no longer a viable strategy in finding the extremum?



https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions

The quick answer is that that extremum may not lie within the constraints. Consider minimizing $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$,  $s.t. $ $ \; x>1$. Setting both partial derivatives gives the solution (0,0), which is not in the feasible region.
In the book's case, the feasible region seems to be a line, so any change in $y_1$ must have a corresponding change in $y_2$. It is not guaranteed that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_1} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_2} = 0$ lies on the line.

So wherever the optimum is, it's no longer guaranteed that the partial derivatives will be zero because, with the constraint in place, the optimum no longer looks like the top of a mountain where it's "flat" in all directions; the optimum might be "sloped" in either direction (or both). Am I understanding it correctly?

Yes, you are understanding correctly. A 1D example is min $f(x) = x^2$, s.t. $x>=1$.
$f'(x) = 2x = 0 $ at $x=0$, but the optimal point is $x=1$. At the optimal point, $f'(1) = 2(1) = 2$.

You may recall from a previous Calculus course or text that when optimizing, one checks the critical points (where the derivative(s) is zero) and the end points.  The straightforward example is :
Extremize the line $y = 2x + 3$ on $[-1,4]$.
The derivative is always nonzero.  Also, a line with nonzero slope has extrema at the endpoints of the interval of investigation.
When you add constraints, you introduce boundaries to the feasible region.  Don't forget to check for extrema on the boundaries.
